# Resolving dependencies with Ninject using parameters from request

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, httprequest, ninject

I've got several implementations of the same service registered in request scope. I want Ninject to resolve this dependency taking into account some parameters from request. Let's say there is one default implementation and some customized implementations for special types of users calling my API.

Most preferably, I would like to load whole assemblies without having to register every service manually (all services can implement some interface (e.g. IInjectable) that would, besides marking them as the ones to register with ninject, encapsulate those extra parameters that would tell ninject when to select them instead of the default impl).

I don't want my services to have any dependency on ninject.

What is the best way to:

1. add parameters from web request to ninject's request?
2. write generic provider/factory to create instance of an object based on parameters from point 1?
3. write a loader that would register services?

Or maybe there is another dependency injector out there that is better suited for the job?